# Spring Boot JSON to Multiple POJO classes from API Response Body

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm creating an application that takes a user's coordinates, the coordinates within a weather API are sent for a JSON request body, then the JSON response body is mapped to multiple POJO's.

The issue I'm having is trying to figure out how do to that with Jackson as far as mapping each part of the response body. I'm pretty new to the framework so a pointer in the right direction would be helpful.

Response Body Example:

```
{
    "location": {
        "name": "Lake Tamarisk",
        "region": "California",
        "country": "United States of America",
        "lat": 33.81,
        "lon": -115.34,
        "tz_id": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "localtime_epoch": 1629239816,
        "localtime": "2021-08-17 15:36"
    },
    "current": {
        "last_updated_epoch": 1629239400,
        "last_updated": "2021-08-17 15:30",
        "temp_c": 36.4,
        "temp_f": 97.5,
        "is_day": 1,
        "condition": {
            "text": "Partly cloudy",
            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
            "code": 1003
        },
        "wind_mph": 12.1,
        "wind_kph": 19.4,
        "wind_degree": 176,
        "wind_dir": "S",
        "pressure_mb": 1006.0,
        "pressure_in": 29.72,
        "precip_mm": 0.0,
        "precip_in": 0.0,
        "humidity": 36,
        "cloud": 6,
        "feelslike_c": 39.3,
        "feelslike_f": 102.7,
        "vis_km": 10.0,
        "vis_miles": 6.0,
        "uv": 9.0,
        "gust_mph": 13.9,
        "gust_kph": 22.3
    }
}
```

POJO Classes:

```
Location, Condition, Current
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the class hierarchy map the JSON structure. There should be at least 4 classes. A root class holds the JSON data and 3 classes you mentioned.

```java
class Response {
    Location location;
    Current current;
}

class Current {
    String lastUpdatedEpoch;
    ......
    Condition condition;
}

class Condition {
    String text;
    .......
}

class Location {
    String name;
    ......
}
```

And finally use some strategy like annotaion **@JsonNaming** to convert camel case to snake case.

Comment: Edit: Turns out I'm an idiot and forgot the default constructor in Root :facepalm